# Algorithms with O(n/log(n)) complexity

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

Are there any famous algorithms with this complexity?

I was thinking maybe a skip list where levels of the nodes are not determined by the number of tails coin tosses, but instead are use a number generated randomly (with uniform distribution) from the (1,log(n)) period to determine the level of the node. Such a data structure would have a find(x) operation with the complexity of O(n/log(n)) (I think, at least). I was curious whether there was anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common to see algorithms whose runtime is of the form O(n<sup>k</sup> / log n) or O(log n / log log n) when using [the method of Four Russians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_Four_Russians) to speed up an existing algorithm. The classic Four Russians speedup reduces the cost of doing a matrix/vector product on Boolean matrices from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(n<sup>2</sup> / log n). The standard dynamic programming algorithm for sequence alignment on two length-n strings runs in time O(n<sup>2</sup>), which can be decreased to O(n<sup>2</sup> / log n) by using a similar trick.

Similarly, the prefix parity problem - in which you need to maintain a sequence of Boolean values while supporting the "flip" and "parity of the prefix of a sequence" operations can be solved in time O(log n / log log n) by using a Four-Russians speedup. (Notice that if you express the runtime as a function of k = log n, this is O(k / log k).