# Algorithm with O(log N^3/M) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to write an algorithm with O(log N^3/M) time complexity. However, I am not sure about log N/M part. I'd be grateful if someone could confirm if my algorithm is correct.

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i = i*2) // log N
  for (int i = 1; i < N; i = i*2) // log N
    *for (int i = 1; i < N; i += M+i*2) // log N/M
```

* If `for (int i = 1; i < N; i += M)` has O(N/M) time complexity, and O(log N) requires `i` to be multiplied by a constant then the conclusion is that O(log N/M) can be achieved if we add the constant to `i` and multiply it by another constant at the same time.

What would be an algorithm for O(N/log N) time complexity?

Comment: Do you mean log(N^3/M)  or log(N^3) / M ?

Comment: The last part of your question [is answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176736/algorithms-with-on-logn-complexity/39215822#39215822).

Comment: O(log(N^3/M)) would be correct.

Comment: You are using the same index over and over again (it's always `i`), so code will not compile. Also, middle loop is iterating while `i < N`, I think you meant `i < M`.

Comment: I know that code will not compile. I used `i` in all three loops to keep it as simple as possible. I meant `i < N`. If I understand big O notation correctly then O(log N^3/M) equals to O(log N) + O(log N) + O(log N / M).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that :
`for (int i = 1; i < N; i += M+i*2)` is not O(log(N/M)) 
because lets say that the loop will run for k times then we have:
k*M + 2^k >=N -> which doesn't leads to k=O(log(N/M)).

Instead you could write:

```
for (int i = 1; i < N/M; i =i*2)
```

this is obviously O(log(N/M)).

Comment: The equation should be something like **3^k + M*3^k = N** which should lead to **k=O(log(N/M))**. But I agree that the loop you suggested is much better!

Comment: Are you sure `i += i*2` is correct? Shouldn't it be `i = i*2`?